# How to get JSON data as RTF format in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am trying to handle JSON data which is coming from API service in ANGULAR2,in RTF format.

I don't know what to write.
Here is a sample code

```
return this.http.get(url,{responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
    (res) => {
        return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' })
    })
```

This code is for Excel format.
I want for the RTF format.
What will be application type?

Comment: `json` data coming as `rtf` handled as `vnd.ms-excel`?

Comment: Byte stream data to RTF

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the Content-Type as

```
this.http.get(url,{
                headers : new Headers(('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'),
                responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
    (res) => {
        return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' })
    })
```

Comment: I am asking for  RTF not for EXCEL

Comment: try application/rtf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types